# Post value from javascript to Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

In our MVC project we are using the following javascript function and we have ensured that this is a working function without any errors.

```
function GetSelectedItems() {
        var newItemIDs = [];
        $("#SelectItems  tbody").find('tr').each(
        function () {

            var id = $(this).find('#hfID').val();
            var IsAdd = $(this).hasClass('k-state-selected');

            if (IsAdd == true) {
                newItemIDs.push(id);
            }

        });
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
        $.post("/Form8Invoice/AddItemToCart", { NewItemIDs: newItemIDs });
```

However when posting the array values to Controller, it seems that the values are not getting properly passed. The controller action method is given below for quick reference.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddItemToCart(string[] newItemIDs, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            if (newItemIDs != null)
            {
                float grandTotal = 0;
                string currentLocation = GetCurrentLocation();
                foreach (string itemID in newItemIDs)
                {
                    Location location = new Location();
                    Stock stock = new Stock();
                    float UnitPrice = 0;
                    float SellingPrice = 0;

                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLocation))
                    {
                        List<Stock> stokList = _stockRepositoty.GetStocksByItemId(new Guid(itemID)).ToList();
                        stock = stokList[0];
                    }
                    else if (currentLocation != "admin")
                    {
                        location = _locationRepository.GetLocationByName(currentLocation);
                        stock = _stockRepositoty.GetStockByItemIdAndLocation(new Guid(itemID), location.LocationId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<Stock> stokList = _stockRepositoty.GetStocksByItemId(new Guid(itemID)).ToList();
                        stock = stokList[0];
                    }

                    if (stock != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stock.UnitPrice.ToString()))
                        {
                            UnitPrice = float.Parse(stock.UnitPrice.ToString());
                            SellingPrice = UnitPrice; // + tax - discount
                        }
                    }

                    if (_cartItemsRepository.IsItemAlreadyAdded(GetCurrentLocation(), GetCurrentUser(), new Guid(itemID)))
                    {
                        CartItem cartItem = _cartItemsRepository.GetItem(GetCurrentLocation(), GetCurrentUser(), new Guid(itemID));
                        int Quantity = cartItem.Quantity;
                        cartItem.Quantity = cartItem.Quantity + 1;
                        _cartItemsRepository.UpdateItems(cartItem);

                        float NetAmount = SellingPrice * cartItem.Quantity;
                        grandTotal = grandTotal + NetAmount;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();
                        cartItem.LocationName = GetCurrentLocation();
                        cartItem.UserName = GetCurrentUser();
                        cartItem.ItemId = new Guid(itemID);
                        cartItem.Quantity = 1;
                        _cartItemsRepository.InsertItems(cartItem);

                        float NetAmount = SellingPrice * cartItem.Quantity;
                        grandTotal = grandTotal + NetAmount;
                    }


                }

                ViewBag.GrandTotal = grandTotal.ToString();
                _cartItemsRepository.Save();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the issue only after hosted the website in IIS. In development environment everything is working properly.

Comment: change your controller parameter to match the Json one. It needs to be `string[] NewItemIDs`

Comment: Did you try
$.post("/Form8Invoice/AddItemToCart", JSON.stringify(newItemIDs));

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the capitalization of the parameter property wrong. Try this:

```
$.post("/Form8Invoice/AddItemToCart", { newItemIDs: newItemIDs });
```

Comment: In Asp.Net MVC matches are case insensitive and do not depend on the parameter order.

Comment: I'm getting the issue only after hosted the website in IIS. In development environment everything is working properly.